# SGD shows the same convergence behaviour as batch gradient descent when using adaptive learning rate?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent, stochastic-approximation

**SGD shows the same convergence behaviour as batch gradient descent when using adaptive learning rate ?**

I dont understand why he claimed that. I couldnt find any reference about it in any paper.

> However, it has been shown that when we slowly decrease the learning
>   rate, SGD shows the same convergence behaviour as batch gradient
>   descent, almost certainly converging to a local or the global minimum
>   for non-convex and convex optimization respectively.

Source : http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/